# Can I make Azure pipeline stages that are independent but still run in series?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline which takes a number of boolean parameters to decide which stages to run. I would like each stage to be independent so that if I select Stage #3 only it'll run and not be dependent on a previous stage being selected as well. I have added `dependsOn: []` to achieve this. However, of the stages that are selected, I would also like them to run in series and not in parallel due to some conflicts with multiple stages accessing the same resources. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help or if you need any further assistance

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you need to use boolean parameters to determine which stages to run and keep the stages run in series.

In this case, you can use the [If expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) to determine which stages to run.

By default, stages will be run in the order defined, so you can remove dependsOn: [].

Here is the YAML example:

```
parameters:
- name: RunStage1
  type: boolean 
  default: true
- name: RunStage2
  type: boolean 
  default: true
- name: RunStage3
  type: boolean 
  default: true
- name: RunStage4
  type: boolean 
  default: true

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- ${{ if contains(parameters.RunStage1, 'true') }}:
  - stage:  test
    jobs:
    - job:  A
      steps: 
      - script:  echo "test"
- ${{ if contains(parameters.RunStage2, 'true') }}:
  - stage:  test1
    jobs:
    - job:  A
      steps: 
      - script:  echo "test"
- ${{ if contains(parameters.RunStage3, 'true') }}:
  - stage:  test2
    jobs:
    - job:  A
      steps: 
      - script:  echo "test"
- ${{ if contains(parameters.RunStage4, 'true') }}:
  - stage:  test3
    jobs:
    - job:  A
      steps: 
      - script:  echo "test"
```

When we run the Pipeline, we can select the related parameters.

[image]

If we select multiple stages, the stages will run in order.

[image]

On the other hand, you can also not use boolean parameters to determine which stages to run. You can consider using the built-in feature: **stages to run** option to select the stages.

For example:

[image]

In this case, you don't need to define parameters to determine which stages to run.